# If $\mathcal{L}:A \rightarrow B$ is considered to be a linear map, are A and B vector spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

$c\mathcal{L}\{f(x)+g(x)\}=\mathcal{L}\{cf(x)\}+\mathcal{L}\{cg(x)\}$ seems to imply that the laplace transform is a linear map. Given that it's domain is $A$ and its range is $B$, does that imply that $A$ and $B$ are vector spaces?

If yes, what are they? How would you show closure under addition and scalar multiplication, etc?

Finally, what would the standard basis for those spaces look like?

I'm taking undergraduate differential equations and my first graduate linear algebra course. I happened to be going over Laplace Transforms and Matrices of Linear maps and was wondering if I could find a way to make a matrix out of Laplace.

Comment: $A$ is the integrable functions, and $B$ is the holomorphic functions. I don't think there's a standard basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The domain will be any vector space $A$ where $\mathcal L$ makes sense. You can take for instance $A=C[0,1]$. Usually, you can take $A$ to be the space of Borel functions locally of bounded variation. The codomain, any vector space that contains the image.

When dealing with infinite-dimensional vector spaces, basis are not that useful. There are some extended notions of bases that work (like Schauder bases in Banach spaces and, more importantly, orthonormal bases on Hilbert spaces). Thinking of linear operators over an infinite-dimensional space as matrices does not lead to anything fruitful.

Comment: So the domain and codomain would definitely be infinite dimensional? And that would mean that I definitely couldn't represent a matrix of the map?

Comment: You can take the domain to be finite-dimensional, if you want. You can fix a single function $f$, consider its scalar multiples and then you have a 1-dimensional vector space $A$. Then you can take $B$ to consist of the scalar multiples of $\mathcal L f$. You take $\{f\}$ as a basis of $A$, $\{\mathcal L f\}$ as a basis of $B$, and the matrix of $\mathcal L$ is $[1]$. Not particularly useful. Usually you would want to apply $\mathcal L$ to many functions so yes, you will have $A$  and $B$ infinite-dimensional. And (plain) bases in infinite dimension is not something you want to deal with.